# Converting Predefined Macros (Verilog) to VHDL

Tags: verilog, vhdl

I came across this and was hoping someone could help me with it.

From my readings, the "Hello World" will only be printed during the simulation process. I would like to convert this Verilog code to VHDL. More specifically, I would like to use this feature in VHDL where I only want the code to be executed in simulation.
Readings: https://docs.xilinx.com/r/2021.2-English/ug900-vivado-logic-simulation/Predefined-Macros

```
`ifdef XILINX_SIMULATOR 
   print "Hello World!";
`endif
```

However, I understand that there is no macro in VHDL. Is there any other way I can code such that the code is only executed during simulation?
I am currently using Vivado ML Edition 2021.1.

Comment: So a specific simulator defines this macro. Did you read the documentation of your VHDL simulator to find similar "mechanics"? For example, GHDL uses [this](https://ghdl.github.io/ghdl/using/Simulation.html#cmdoption-ghdl-gGENERIC) and references [JSON-for-VHDL](https://github.com/Paebbels/JSON-for-VHDL).

Comment: I tried searching online but could not find similar "mechanics". I am a beginner in hardware coding, hence do not really know where and how to find these information. Appreciate if you could help!

Comment: Your simulator should come with documentation. Did you look into it and tried some tutorials?

Comment: VHDL has no macros, and so this behaviour cannot be directly replicated. VHDL 2019 adds conditional compilation which might provide some similar abilities, but support for this feature is currently limited to some paid for simulators, namely ActiveHDL and Questa.  You could replicate the behaviour with top level generics as @thebusybee suggests.

Comment: You might also want to add in _what_ use case you need conditional statements. I would not expect it in implementations meant to be synthesized, and implementations for simulation like test-benches are only simulated.

Comment: You can use the -- synthesis translate_on / off comments to turn off part of a constant initialization for synthesis vs simulation. And then generate statements for code based on off that constant.

Answer (score 1):

VHDL-2019 added conditional analysis. It would translate to

```
`if XILINX_SIMULATOR /= ""
   print "Hello World!"; 
`end if
```

However most tools do not support VHDL-2019, and Vivado does not even have full support of VHDL-2008.

But you can use comment pragmas

```
-- pragma translate_off
   print "Hello World!";
-- pragma translate_on
```